# How to align HTML labels using CSS3 flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, label, alignment

I have setup a codepen so you can see what I want.  Click here to open the codepen:  https://codepen.io/tbellmer/pen/RdxBdQ

I am relatively new at this and while the form is functional, I need help with the aesthetics.  I would like to have both the **Action:** and **Comment:** labels be right aligned.  I am trying to use the most modern techniques so not looking to use a table or float.

My code uses a flexbox to have an aside section and main section.  Can I use a flexbox or grid to do what I want?  Also notice that I used a

for some vertical spacing and suspect there is a better way to do this as well.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <aside class="col sidebar">
      <p class = 'ctr'>Welcome</p>
    </aside>
    <section class="col main">
      <h1 class='ctr'>Title</h1>
      <hr>
      <form action = '#'>
        <label for = 'combo'>Action: </label>
        <select id = 'combo' name = 'response' required>
          <option value = ''>--none--</option>
          <option value = 'A'>Approved</option>
          <option value = 'R'>Rejected</option>
        </select>
        <p></p>   <!-- has to be a better way to get space -->
        <!-- want to have both Action: and Comment: labels line up to right -->
        <label for = 'comment'>Comment: <label>
        <input type=text id='comment' size='40' name='comment'>
        <p></p>
        <input class = 'button' type = 'submit' value = 'Submit' id = 'submit'>
        <input class = 'button' type = 'reset'  value = 'Cancel'>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can put the same width on labels to have it nice aligned and have the input starts in the one line.

Comment: you can reset display to resize them such  `label {display:inline-block;width:5em;text-align:right}` or whatever size you want . flexbox is not required here, else the method is what you done for main and aside set a width to each via flex or width

Comment: Please add this to my codepen and see the results:  label {display:inline-block;width:5em;text-align:right} - it does not work

Comment: label is inline, you need to reset display to be able to size them. you took  2 rules out  of three ... the one missing is the one that allows to use the two others ......

Comment: I have reset my codepen to show all three as suggested.  The reason I removed the display: inline-block is because that really messes things up.  See codepen now with that added back in.  that is not the desired result.

Comment: it is also because you did not close properly the second label https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywvKBj  (4em is a bit short for the word Comment 5 woks better )

Comment: Purrfect!  thank you sooo much G-Cyr, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `div` inside the `form` tag just like i did below and add a class with the

CSS

```
.display-align {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-gap:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <div class="display-align">
        <div>
            <label for = 'combo'>Action: </label>
            <br><br>
            <label for = 'comment'>Comment: <label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select id = 'combo' name = 'response' required">
                <option value = ''>--none--</option>
                <option value = 'A'>Approved</option>
                <option value = 'R'>Rejected</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type=text id='comment' size='40' name='comment'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>                
    <div>
        <input class = 'button' type = 'submit' value = 'Submit' id = 'submit'>
        <input class = 'button' type = 'reset'  value = 'Cancel'>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can use the `<br>` tag to break a line or still use the `<p>` .

But may I suggest to you use this instead(its basically the same, but different lol).
I use the same CSS class in this code.

```
<form>
    <fieldset style="max-width: 400px;">
        <legend>Title</legend>
        <div class="display-align">
            <div>
                <label for = 'combo'>Action: </label>
                <br><br>
                <label for = 'comment'>Comment: <label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id = 'combo' name = 'response' required">
                    <option value = ''>--none--</option>
                    <option value = 'A'>Approved</option>
                    <option value = 'R'>Rejected</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <input type=text id='comment' size='40' name='comment'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>            
        <div>
            <input class = 'button' type = 'submit' value = 'Submit' id = 'submit'>
            <input class = 'button' type = 'reset'  value = 'Cancel'>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```